# Did amazon just release a solution to the multiple server issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I'm working on a meteor application, and one of the things I'm scared of is that no one knows how to make one run on multiple machines.

Amazon just announced this: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/03/11/announcing-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-node-js/

Would this solve that problem, by providing an essentially infinite sized machine? Or do I completely misunderstand AWS? Or is it ridiculous to be worried about this because no meteor app will ever use more than 30GB of RAM?

Sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: Do you mean a solution to horizontal scaling?

Comment: @Akshat I've read that there isn't a way to put a basic meteor app on multiple servers. I'm wondering if this solves that problem by supplying a server that'll always be as big as necessary.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the use case do you mean to use meteor for a very high traffic site on multiple servers (horizontal scaled), for which I know the dev team is working hard on a ddp proxy to help or the same app hosted on multiple servers for individual sites/different data on each one?

Comment: @Akshat Very high traffic app that can't fit on a single server. With on database

Comment: Sam Hatoum provided a good response.  I'd only add that you're thinking of vertical scaling with 'essentially infinite sized machine'.  What AWS just announced with Elastic Beanstalk for Node is horiztonal scaling... meaning 'essentially infinite *number* of machines to run an app on concurrently'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amazon Beanstalk uses a predefined CloudFormations template along with some preconfigured AMI's to allow you to easily deploy applications. The different flavors, this new Node one being one of them, are pre-configured tech-stacks to use.

The templates as they are don't solve the meteor horizontal scaling. That is, to run meteor on multiple machines. To do that, you'll need to have meteor persist its WebSocket states so other servers in the cluster can share it.

The Amazon Elastic Load Balancers (ELB) allow TCP traffic, which is needed for scaling WebSocket traffic. The ELBs also support Session Affinity or Sticky Sessions (so many names for this). However this is not enough. Imagine I log on to one server, and I get to stay there. Then you logon to another server and stay there. Now we have two different servers, talking to us separately. If those servers shared the WebSocket state however.

SocketIO + Redis can be used together to do this using a RedisStore, but this is not currently supported in meteor. I would expect they'll support this eventually as it would be needed for viable production-ready product - unless they come up with some other magic to achieve the same goal.

You're right to be worried about it as servers do sometimes just die, especially in a virtualized environment. Clustering is not just about performance, it's also about high-availability.

Answer (score 1):

I think [modulus.io](http://modulus.io/features) will probably work best because of their feature of "Session Affinity"

"Our load balancers ensure when users hit a Servo, they are sent back to that same Servo for all subsequent activity. This reduces the complexity of applications by allowing for in-memory state information."

However, I have not actually tried deploying a meteor application there.

They also have a blog [post](http://blog.modulus.io/demeteorizer) specifically about meteor